# How to get HTML of HtmlControl object in backend

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a short snippet of C# code like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl titleH3 = new HtmlGenericControl("h3");
titleH3.Attributes.Add("class", "accordion");

HtmlAnchor titleAnchor = new HtmlAnchor();
titleAnchor.HRef = "#";
titleAnchor.InnerText = "Foo Bar";
titleH3.Controls.Add(titleAnchor);
```

What I want is a way to return a string that looks like this:

```
<h3 class="accordion"><a href="#">Foo Bar</a></h3>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the method that I have used in the past to get a control's rendered HTML ahead of time (make sure to include `System.IO`):

```
protected string ControlToHtml(Control c)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    c.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

Returns this for your test case:

```
<h3 class="accordion"><a href="#">Foo Bar</a></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that you can use to extend any HtmlControl to have a Render() method:

```
public static string Render(this HtmlAnchor TheAnchor)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    TheAnchor.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
    return sw.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: ...or extend all HTMLControls at once by changing HtmlAnchor to HtmlControl in the above code. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't there be a Render method that forces it to emit its own HTML?